# Where can I find a memory map for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, memory-management

I remember that, back in the days of the Commodore 64, I had a Reference Book showing me which part of memory was assigned to do what.

I was wondering if something of the likes was available for Mac OS X.

My iMac has a 1TB hard disk and I'd like to know where the free space is, which part is allocated to the display, etc.

Any resources where I could learn more about this subject would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest doing some background reading on the design of operating systems and then re-condsider the question. The canonical undergraduate textbook is [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Operating-Systems-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/0138134596).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard disk is not "memory" in the sense you're thinking of. None of it is used for active apps, the display, etc...

You're thinking of ram, but on modern OSs that isn't divided by task like it may have been on past systems. Where things are located is dynamically assigned as needed, and intentionally randomized for security reasons (google for ASLR for the randomization).

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the "`Utilities`" folder hidden in your Macintosh "`/Applications`" folder, you'll see an application named "Activity Monitor".

Open that, and you'll be able to see both memory usage (mine looks like this):

[image: Memory Usage]

And disk usage looks like this:

[image: Disk Usage]

Now these two views may look a little boring, or underwhelming, compared to what you might have seen with your Commodore 64 (or in my case, I was using a Trash-80 Color Computer).... but these screenshots are just a quick slice of data from about 10 seconds of looking at each view.  If you leave the disk usage screen up for more than 10 seconds, you'll see the I/O ribbon gets more detailed with time.  And there's probably more functionality hidden in there that I haven't even noticed yet.  Try it out.

Comment: Hey Michael, Thanks for you're helpful answer. You guessed correctly: I use to have a Commodore 64 some 30 years ago! I remembered that I could read or "Poke" into certain areas of memory, such as the one corresponding to the display. I thought the Mac worked in the same way, but it seems that things have changed quite a bit since!